# Why is "en Europe" wrong in "Le Portugal est un petit pays d'Europe"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

In the following sentence over [Duolingo French course](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/26847416):

> Le Portugal est un petit pays **d**'Europe.

However, *en Europe* is considered wrong and other people on the forum wondered the same question.

Why is *en Europe* considered wrong, and how can I know when to use *de* and when to use *en* when referring to countries or continents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **1.** Why is **en Europe** considered wrong?

You can write, answering to the question "**What** is the Portugal ?":

> *Le Portugal est **un petit pays**.*

*Être* means "has the characteristic of being".

and, answering to the question "**Where** is the Portugal?":

> *Le Portugal est **en Europe**.*

*Être* means "is located".

However,

> *Le Portugal est **un petit pays en Europe**.*

despite being grammatically correct is unidiomatic and would be parsed somewhat as “Portugal is a small country when in Europe”. That might be understood to mean "Portugal is possibly a larger country elsewhere" which doesn't make sense. Countries are not known for traveling.

We do not juxtapose both complements, moreover without any conjunction, especially because *être* hasn't the same meaning.

Duolingo is right when considering the answer :

> *Le Portugal est un petit pays **d**'Europe*

to be the right one. This is indeed the usual construction to refer to a country that is part of a continent or a larger group of countries.

Alternatives can make clear the complements are disjunct:

> *Le Portugal est un petit pays **et il est** en Europe.*
>
> *Le Portugal est en Europe **et c'est** un petit pays.*

or correctly link its location to the country:

> *Le Portugal est un petit pays **européen**.*
>
> *Le Portugal est un petit pays **situé en Europe**.*

Finally, *un petit pays en Europe* would be fine in this sentence:

> *Le Portugal est considéré comme un petit pays en Europe.*

but the meaning is different:

> Outside Europe, people might consider differently the Portugal size.

---

> **2.** How can I know when to use *de* and when to use *en* when referring to countries or continents?

*De* is a preposition that mark a belonging relationship, similar to "of", e.g.:

> *Les États-Unis **d**'Amérique* not *<s>Les États-Unis en Amérique</s>*
>
> *The United States **of** America* not *<s>The United States in America</s>*

*En* is a preposition that mark a location like "in".

> *My life **in** America* not *<s>My life of America</s>*
>
> *Ma vie **en** Amérique* not *<s>Ma vie d'Amérique</s>*

---

<sub>PS: Whatever its size, Portugal is a great country :-)</sub>

Comment: (Neither _un petit pays_ nor _en Europe_ is a direct object; they are predicative complements.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet C'est vrai, bien sûr. Merci..

Answer (score 5):

Ce choix est strictement une question d'usage, mais c'est un usage selon certains principes plutôt solides.

**La préposition « de » est généralement utilisée, mais avec une modification selon le genre.**

> Pour les noms propres féminin l'article n'est pas utilisé (**de, d'**)

- d'Afrique (Le Togo est un pays d'Afrique)
- d'Érythrée
- de Géorgie (EUA, Europe de l'Est)
- d'Argentine
- d'Allemagne
- d'Amérique
- de France (les villes de France, une ville de France, les villages de France, un village de France, les rivières de France, une rivière de France, les plages de France)
- de Bretagne
- de Corrèze
- de Poitou-Charentes
- de Champagne (caves et vignobles de Champagne)
  …

> Pour les noms masculins et les noms pluriels l'article reste.(**de l', du, des**)

- de l'Illinois
- de l'Arctique (les animaux de l'Arctique)
- du Soudan
- du Brésil
  …
- des Alpes (Chamonix est une ville des Alpes)
- des Pyrénées
- des Causses (villages des Causses)
- des Canaries (ville des Canaries)
- des Antilles (les îles des Antilles)
- des Açores
  …

> Lorsque le nom est un nom commun l'article est utilisé (**de l', du, de la, des**)

- océan (Sri Lanka est une île de l'Océan Indien)
- continent (Les Alpes sont une chaîne de montagnes du Continent Européen)
- bassin (les villes du Bassin Parisien)
- massif (Limoges est une ville du Massif Central)
- île (les communes des îles Canaries)
- désert (les fleurs du désert de Mojave)
- région (les vins de la région Champagne)
  …

On peut cependant utiliser « en », « dans » ou « de » selon la construction et le nom;
À la question « Milan est une ville de quel pays ? » on peut répondre de deux façons;

- Milan est une ville **d'** Italie.
- C'est **en** Italie. (« en » ou « à » pour les pays)

Question : Où se trouve Madagascar ?

- Madagascar est une île **de** l'Océan indien.
- C'est **dans** l'océan indien. (« dans » pour les océans et les mers)

> Lorsque le groupe nominal n'est pas simple et indique une sous-classe ou une entité non spécifique à l'endroit les prépositions  suivantes sont utilisées soit comme alternative à « de » soit uniquement : **en, dans**.

- les villes et villages de caractère **en** Corrèze (on pourrait aussi dire « de »)
- les fleurs et la végétation **dans** le désert de Mojave (on pourrait aussi dire « du »)
- vignobles et découvertes **en** Champagne (« de » n'est pas possible)

**Il y a des exceptions**

- du Poitou-Charentes *et* de Poitou-Charentes
- de l'Inde
- **de la** Corrèze *et* **de** Corrèze
- les plages **de la** Floride *ou* les plages de Floride
- vignobles **de la** Champagne *ou* vignoble de Champagne
- La Corrèze est un département **sur** le plateau de Millevaches.
  …

Comment: This may warrant a separate question, but what exactly are the criteria for the apparent article deletion that occurs here? It’s generally _la France_, _l’Europe_, _l’Afrique_ and _l’Italie_ with article, just like _l’Océan Indien_, _les Alpes_ and _le Massif Central_; so why is it not also _une ville de la France/de l’Italie_, _un pays de l’Europe/de l’Afrique_ – or indeed _une ville de Massif Central/d’Alpes_ or _une île d’Océan Indien_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I haven't gone further into the question or I would have given the results if any; your very interesting remark reminds me of  something even more puzzling: you do not say "une ville d'Inde" but "une ville de l'Inde" or "une ville des Indes"; here is one more without searching too much: "une ville de l'Illinois". I'm going to see what I can get besides a list of exceptions. It seems that when the noun is not a proper noun the article remains: , "une ville de l'Île de France"," une ville du Bassin Parisien"; but still there are exceptions.

Comment: I suppose “une ville d’Inde” might cause some offence to its residents when spoken. ;-) I may just ask this as a separate question. Perhaps there is some kind of logic to it beyond just some exceptions. (**Edit:** Bah, I shouldn’t attempt puns at one in the morning. My brain somehow made _d’Inde_ = _dingue_. Wrong consonant, brain!)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Strangely enough, your second comment came in 2 minutes after I sent my first, which contains your idea, and more, you very example.

Comment: My second comment was a reply to yours, hence the identical example. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You could even have gone a little further: ''une vie d'dingue"; You say in French "Une fois n'est pas coutume".