# Histoire de (la) bande dessinée : « de la » ou « de » ?

Tags: grammaire, articles, absence-d-article

Ce n'est pas clair pour moi quand il faut utiliser *de* et quand *du/de la*.

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit de plusieurs groupes d'acceptions du mot « histoire ».

1. On utilise « **du** » (contraction pour « de le ») et « **de la** » lorsqu'il s'agit de « histoire » dans le sens de faits importants qui se sont déroulés dans le cadre d'une nation, d'un grand projet, de l'évolution d'une technologie, d'un art, etc., ces faits étant généralement enregistrés et étudiés par un historien. On décrit par ces GN une histoire **particulière**.

   - L'histoire de la civilisation orientale, L'histoire du cinéma, Une histoire de l'Amérique Latine, l'histoire de l'art médiéval, l'histoire de la Belgique, l'histoire de la bande dessinée…

Exception : L'histoire **de** France (uniquement), histoire de Belgique (plus fréquent) (user **jlliagre**, voir commentaires)

2. On utilise « **de** » lorsque « histoire » signifie « récit », « conte », « fable », « narration », … On décrit alors par ces GN une **sorte** de récit.

   - Les histoires d'amour, les histoires de sorcellerie, une histoire de pirates…
3. On utilise aussi « **de** » lorsque « histoire » signifie « évènement », « suite de faits réels ou non » comme dans un fait divers par exemple. On décrit dans ce cas un évènement (réel ou fictif).

   - des histoires de vol à la tire, une sale histoire d'argent, une histoire de comptes frauduleux, une histoire de proxénétisme, une histoire de femme trompée
4. Noter :   une histoire de fous (ici « fou » ne signifie pas que les personnes impliquées dans le récit sont des fou, il ne s'agit pas d'un récit dans lequel on trouve des fous; il s'agit d'un récit dans lequel les gens et les évènement ont un caractère si irrationnel, si contraire à la raison qu'on le considère comme si de la sorte de l'histoire avec des fous, soit écrit par un fou ou des fous.)

Comment: Ça n'explique pas *l'histoire de France* mais *l'histoire de la Belgique* et *la géographie de la France*.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est une exception, je n'en vois pas d'autres ; dans cette réponse je me limite au mot «  histoire » ; il pourrait y avoir beaucoup de travail : voir par exemple https://french.stackexchange.com/a/33345/17649

Comment: C'est une exception dans le sens où l'on s'attend à trouver l'article défini devant France, mais contrairement à ce que je pensais, *[histoire de Belgique](http://www.bibliomonde.com/livre/nouvelle-histoire-belgique-volume-1830-1905-4799.html)* semble plus courant qu' *histoire de la Belgique* et plus encore qu'*histoire belge*... A l'inverse, *histoire de Suisse* est très rare face à *histoire de la Suisse*. D'autre part "*de*" seul sera aussi naturellement utilisé dans d'autres cas comme *histoire de Rome* ou *histoire de Cuba*.